# Combining tasks results in a dictionary

Tags: c#, task

I'm trying to parallelize work that relies on external resources, and combine it into a single resulting dictionary.

To illustrate my need, imagine I want to download a set of file, and put each result in a dictionary, where the key is the url:

```
string[] urls = { "http://msdn.microsoft.com", "http://www.stackoverflow.com", "http://www.google.com" };

var fileContentTask = GetUrls(urls);

fileContentTask.Wait();

Dictionary<string, string> result = fileContentTask.Result;
// Do something
```

However, I was able to code the `GetUrls` methode. I can generate all the tasks, but I didn't found how to consolidate the result in the dictionary:

```
static Task<Dictionary<string,string>> GetUrls(string[] urls)
{
    var subTasks = from url in urls
                   let wc = new WebClient()
                   select wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);

    return Task.WhenAll(subTasks); // Does not compile
}
```

How can I merge the resulting tasks into a dictionary?

Comment: should'nt it be ``Task<List<string>>`` ?

Comment: @EʜsᴀɴSᴀᴊᴊᴀᴅ: no. I need to have the resulting dictionnary to have the url as the key, and the content of the file as the value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to perform the mapping yourself. For example, you could use:

```
static async Task<Dictionary<string,string>> GetUrls(string[] urls)
{
    var tasks = urls.Select(async url =>
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            return new { url, content = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url) };
        };
    }).ToList();
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return results.ToDictionary(pair => pair.url, pair => pair.content);
}
```

Note how the method has to be `async` so that you can use `await` within it.

Comment: Isn't putting await within the select statement actually working sequentially? I mean, isn't each iteration waiting for the completion of the download task before yielding its result ?

Comment: can we use await inside linq expression syntax which OP posted?

Comment: Not compiling here. It seems it does not understand the `async` keyword inside the `Select` method.

Comment: @AndersonPimentel: Try now - I had it in the wrong place :)

Comment: @SteveB: No - the `ToList()` call will return a `List<Task<...>>`, where all the tasks have been *started* in parallel.

Comment: @EʜsᴀɴSᴀᴊᴊᴀᴅ: No, not easily.

Comment: @JonSkeet Working fine now! =D Wouldn't be better to put the `using (var client...` outside the core logic so it only creates a single instance of the `WebClient` class?

Comment: @AndersonPimentel: I don't know whether using a single `WebClient` for multiple concurrent requests is safe. I don't see anything documenting it as such.

Comment: WebClient can't issue concurrent request (tried a long time ago)

Comment: OK. I guess we could use a single instance if we were using `HttpClient`, right?

Comment: @AndersonPimentel: Again, I'm not seeing documentation saying that would be okay.

Comment: Ah! I understand... The async keyword just before the lambda in the select actually transform the whole block into a task. Thanks! As a side note, I found another solution that does not require async/await. ButI guess your's avoid one dictionary instantiation compared to mine.

Comment: @JonSkeet Still on `HttpClient`, [official docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) lists several methods as thread safe and [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/08/07/httpclient-httpclienthandler-and-httpwebrequesthandler.aspx) from Henrik Nielsen on MSDN states that "A single HttpClient can be used to send as many HTTP requests as you want concurrently".

Comment: @AndersonPimentel: Ah, I hadn't seen that bit. Shame they didn't update the "thread safety" section at the bottom which was where I expected thread safety to be documented. So yes, in that case it would make sense to use `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 0):

Something that makes use of your existing linq:

```
static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetUrls(string[] urls)
{
    IEnumerable<Task<string>> subTasks = from url in urls
                   let wc = new WebClient()
                   select wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);

    var urlsAndData = subTasks.Zip(urls, async (data, url) => new { url, data = await data });

    return (await Task.WhenAll(urlsAndData)).ToDictionary(a => a.url, a => a.data);
}
```

But as that does not dispose the `WebClient`, I would refactor out a method to make it like below. I've also added a `Distinct` call as there's no point downloading two urls that are the same only to fall-over when making a dictionary.

```
static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetUrls(string[] urls)
{
    var distinctUrls = urls
        .Distinct().ToList();

    var urlsAndData = 
        distinctUrls
        .Select(DownloadStringAsync)
        .Zip(distinctUrls, async (data, url) => new { url, data = await data });

    return (await Task.WhenAll(urlsAndData)).ToDictionary(a => a.url, a => a.data);
}

private static async Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string url)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        return await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah, which is why I would do the second one, which I will point out as the reason.

Comment: Your second code is incorrect - the `Distinct()` part means that the zip won't necessarily work. I'd suggest just removing the `Distinct()` part.